# Why are the entries of $\det(D)\left[(v^TDu)^{-1}D^{-1}-D^{-1}uv^TD^{-1}\right]$ polynomials in the entries of $D$?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Consider a matrix $M$ whose entries are $n^2$ indeterminates. Apply the partition
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}a&v^T\\ u&D\end{bmatrix}$$
where $a=m_{11}$. Since the entries of $D$ are $(n-1)^2$ indeterminates, it is invertible. Therefore $\det(M)=\det(D)(a-v^TD^{-1}u)$ (see [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) on Wikipedia) and
\begin{align*}M^{-1}&=\begin{bmatrix}(a-v^TD^{-1}u)^{-1}&-(a-v^TD^{-1}u)^{-1}v^TD^{-1}\\ -D^{-1}u(a-v^TD^{-1}u)^{-1}&D^{-1}+D^{-1}u(a-v^TD^{-1}u)^{-1}v^TD^{-1}\end{bmatrix}.\end{align*}
Hence the bottom right subblock of $\mathrm{adj}(M)$ is given by
\begin{align*}&\det(D)(a-v^TD^{-1}u)\left[D^{-1}+D^{-1}u(a-v^TD^{-1}u)^{-1}v^TD^{-1}\right]\\
&=\det(D)\left[(a-v^TD^{-1}u)D^{-1}+D^{-1}uv^TD^{-1}\right]\\
&=a\ \mathrm{adj}(D)-\det(D)\left[(v^TD^{-1}u)D^{-1}-D^{-1}uv^TD^{-1}\right]\end{align*}
and it follows that all entries of $$\det(D)\left[(v^TD^{-1}u)D^{-1}-D^{-1}uv^TD^{-1}\right]$$ are polynomials in the entries of $u,v$ and $D$. However, I cannot directly see why this is the case, as each of the two summands involves two copies of $D^{-1}$ but only one copy of $\det(D)$. Can anyone explain this paradox by a direct argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Too long for a comment.)* Since your expression is bilinear in $u$ and $v$, it suffices prove the statement when $u$ and $v$ are specialised to standard basis vectors. Moreover, as
$\det(D)\left[(v^TD^{-1}u)D^{-1}-D^{-1}uv^TD^{-1}\right]$ is identical to $\det(DP)P\left[\big(v^TP(DP)^{-1}u\big)(DP)^{-1}-(DP)^{-1}uv^TP(DP)^{-1}\right]$ for any permutation matrix $P$, we may assume that $u=v=e_1$.

Thus, the entries of $\det(D)\left[(v^TD^{-1}u)D^{-1}-D^{-1}uv^TD^{-1}\right]$ are polynomials in the entries of $D$ if and only if $\det(D)$ divides $c_{11}c_{ij}-c_{1j}c_{i1}$ for all $i$ and $j$, where $c_{ij}$ denotes the $(i,j)$-th entry of the cofactor matrix of $D$. Yet this is true because by Greg Martin and Erick Wong, *Almost all integer matrices have no integer eigenvalues*, AMM, 116(7): 588-597, 2009 ([preprint](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.0712.3060) at arXiv; see also Greg Martin's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816465)),
$$
c_{11}c_{ij}-c_{1j}c_{i1}
=(-1)^{i+j}\det(D)\det\big(D[\{1,j\}^c,\{1,i\}^c]\big)
$$
when $i,j\ne1$.

However, although the above proof doesn't involve embedding of $D$ into a larger-sized matrix, I am not sure it is any simpler than your block matrix argument.